# How to create a link to a component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want the content of my component be shown in a different view when I click on an item. I don't understand how can I call a component from render. I imagine like this Myitem.  To do this in React, I did it the following way:

```
 content(item) {
    var me = this.state;
    return(
      <Row>
          <Col xs={12} sm={9} md={9} lg={9}>
            <MyComponent item={item}} />
          </Col>
      </Row>      
      )
  }

  render() {
      var me = this.state;
      return(
        <Fragment>
        <Row>
          {ITEMS.map((item, ind) => {
            return(
              <Col key={ind} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                <div onClick={this.content.bind(this, item.item)}>
                </div>
              </Col>
              )
          })}
        </Row>
        {this.content()?this.content():""}
        </Fragment>
      );
```

but the list and content are shown in the same screen.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create another.. component?

Comment: I have created MyComponent and I want to invoke it when I click an item from the render, depend the item send it props.  and I want when MyComponent is displayed not be show the list of items.

Comment: @cabita create routing to navigate different component on click of item list.

Comment: @cabita check this post i created for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/59306622/6544460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short way good example application using react routing, navigating to other component, passing data to navigated component.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
const arr = [{id:1,name:'react'},{id:2,name:'redux'}]
const BasicExample = () =>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/detail" component={Detail} />
    </div>
  </Router>;
  const About = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
  const Home = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      {arr.map(a=>
        <div key={a.id}>
        <strong>{a.id}</strong>
         <Link to={{
           pathname:"/detail",
           state: a
         }}>{a.name}</Link>
        </div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
const Detail=(props)=><h3>Detail-({props.location.state.id}--{props.location.state.name})</h3>
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-96jlq)

Comment: HOw can I hide the<ul> when I click on any link and only show the content?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use links and routes best solution is to use React-Router or Next.js.

but if you insist to do it manually:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-sun-qn4f0

Comment: I'll check how to use React-Router and the example manually, thanks.